# Why can I get into the close vote review queue with no close votes left?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, review

[image]

Before the close reason reform, this screen could never occur.  Now, I can get there, and review things edit or leave open, but not closed.  Assuredly this should not be.

Comment: buuuuugs! bugs everywhere! They're crawling all over the site! ::swats frantically at the monitor::

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Before the close reason reform,

No, it's always been like that.  (At least, I'm sure it happened to me before the new close vote reasons were implemented.)

It makes some sense... you have reviews left, so you could pick "Leave Open."